# How to achieve photoshop like warp in imagick

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I am trying to achieve photoshop like warp using image magick. I tried to move the initial 16 points in the 4x4 grid image to the final 16 points. i have the initial 16 points and the final 16 points.

here points are x, y co-ordinates of the intersection of the grid.

I am using Shepards distortion.

```
convert d1s.png -matte -virtual-pixel transparent -distort Shepards "0,0 0,234  158,0 973,300  316,0 1120,367  474,0 1336,411  0,667 0,842  158,667 810,858  316,667 998,878 474,667 1130,898  0,1333 0,1370  158,1333 700,1396 316,1333 936,1411 474,1333 1084,1418  0,2000 0,1886  158,2000 936,1942  316,2000 1105,1945  474,2000 1321,1900" outputs.png
```

This leads to some unexpected warp.

If any other method is available as well, please do share.

### update:

input image
[image]

output image
[image]

I want to achieve something like this. I have the initial 16 points and the final 16 points.

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to do. Please post your input image and your result from ImageMagick and Photoshop. Also what Photoshop commands did you use to achieve the distortion? Perhaps you want to use a perspective distortion (-distort perspective) in ImageMagick if you have a set of control points. ImageMagick does not have a grid mesh warp function, if that is what you are trying to do.

Comment: @fmw42 please check the update

Comment: ImageMagick does not have such a function. Sorry. You could try OpenCV or skImage. Shepards warp will not do that.

Comment: @fmw42 Apart from Shepard. Is there any method / technique to achieve the resulting image/ shape in ImageMagick

Comment: You are using a bezier warp. ImageMagick does not have that. But you could try the -distort polynomial, which for second order needs at minimum 6 control points. And a third order needs 10. So you have 16 and that should work. See https://imagemagick.org/Usage/distorts/#polynomial

Comment: Also check out http://im.snibgo.com/pinorpush.htm and http://im.snibgo.com/curve3d.htm and http://im.snibgo.com/triangul.htm

Comment: @fmw42. can we distort the image using polynomial at more than 4 coordinates. i couldn't find example that work for my case. I have read about mapping in imagemagick, do you think it will work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183812/discussion-between-tomonso-ejang-and-fmw42).

Answer (score 2):

I have processed your grid image by picking control points at the grid intersections in both the input and output image from Photoshop. I used ImageJ pointpicker plug-in to help me pick and save the control points. See http://bigwww.epfl.ch/thevenaz/pointpicker/

Then I used ImageMagick 2nd order polynomial warp using those control points.

I put the list of control points into an array for both the input and output images. Then I merged them in the format in1 out1 in2 out2 ... in16 out16 (as corresponding pairs).

```
inArr=(17,20
280,22
542,21
806,20
16,286
280,286
542,286
808,285
17,549
280,549
542,550
805,549
17,812
280,812
542,812
806,808)


outArr=(348,13
420,41
522,48
582,66
277,302
328,320
409,346
481,360
230,516
332,548
442,569
516,552
289,748
402,776
542,766
638,713)

list="2"
for ((i=0; i<16; i++)); do
list="$list ${inArr[$i]} ${outArr[$i]}"
done
echo $list


2 17,20 348,13 280,22 420,41 542,21 522,48 806,20 582,66 16,286 277,302 280,286 328,320 542,286 409,346 808,285 481,360 17,549 230,516 280,549 332,548 542,550 442,569 805,549 516,552 17,812 289,748 280,812 402,776 542,812 542,766 806,808 638,713
```

Note that the first entry above is 2, which means that control points will be fit to a 2nd order polynomial.

In the following, before doing the distortion, I have made the area outside your grid lines to be transparent, so that the outside area would not show in the distorted image. I did this by flood filling the outside black area to transparency (color none). The distortion used -virtual-pixel none so that anything outside your input image would be transparent.

```
convert grid.png -fuzz 10% -fill none -draw "matte 0,0 floodfill" -virtual-pixel none -distort polynomial "$list" grid_warp2.png
```

[image]

Here is the 3rd order polynomial results:

```
list="3"
for ((i=0; i<16; i++)); do
list="$list ${inArr[$i]} ${outArr[$i]}"
done
echo $list

3 17,20 348,13 280,22 420,41 542,21 522,48 806,20 582,66 16,286 277,302 280,286 328,320 542,286 409,346 808,285 481,360 17,549 230,516 280,549 332,548 542,550 442,569 805,549 516,552 17,812 289,748 280,812 402,776 542,812 542,766 806,808 638,713

convert grid.png -fuzz 10% -fill none -draw "matte 0,0 floodfill" -virtual-pixel none -distort polynomial "$list" grid_warp3.png
```

[image]

More control points might give a closer result to that of Photoshop.